# SwiftUI: Navigating to a view within the view hierarchy

Tags: swift, navigation, swiftui

**What I have so far:**

I have two views, the first one my `ContentView` will be loaded inside the `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` method in `SceneDelegate` (which is standard). I have embedded a `NavigationView` to the body property of my `ContentView`. The second view `DetailView` can be navigated to via a `NavigationLink`, to navigate back you can use the back button created by the `NavigationView`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Navigate")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Some Title")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail")
        .navigationBarTitle("Another Title")
    }
}
```

Inside `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` method in `SceneDelegate`:

```
let contentView = ContentView()

if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

**What I am trying to do:**

Now I want to navigate to the `DetailView` right away depending on the `connectionOptions` inside the `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` method in `SceneDelegate`.

**My Problem:**

When I just replace `let contentView = ContentView()` with `let contentView = DetailView` depending on the `connectionOptions`, my `ContentView` is not inside my view hierarchy anymore and therefore I don't have the `NavigationView` layout.

**Question:**

How can I navigate to a certain view inside my view hierarchy without losing any of the navigation feature (including the navigation bar, back button, and being able to navigate deeper) created by a `NavigationView` inside another view?

Comment: i *think* the trick is to use `isActive` on your `NavigationLink`. I've used it on a hidden one to automatically trigger a push navigation, and I learned of that trick by a question where someone pointed out that if by setting `isActive` to true you will immediately be taken to the destination. Tie the `isActive value to your model, keep your `ContentView` as is, and if our want your app to open in the detail view, just do it in your model.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense and probably will work but when you have a deep hierarchy with a lot of views, do you really have to set all the isActive parameters to true on all the NavigationLinks?

Comment: I'm not trying to sound critical - and remember, SwiftUI is still in beta - if you have a deep hierarchy where you want your startup view to be one of more than two views, maybe its time to rethink your hierarchy.

Comment: No I am just saying it seems a little circuitous but like you said it’s still a beta. For example when you are using Handoff the view is usually nested a little deeper in the hierarchy.

Comment: @L.Stephan to answer you I need to understand exactly what you are expecting, there are two possibilities: 1) you want your DetailView to have the back button on top and to be able to come back to the ContentView even if you start your app with the DetailView as the first view. 2) you want to have the navigation feature in your DetailView when you use it as your first app view, but just to "navigate deeper" and you are not expecting to be able to come back to the ContentView in this case with the back button. (Please, edit your question accordingly)

Comment: 1) I want the entire navigation feature (including navigating back) to appear in both cases (either ContentView or DetailView is the first view). See edit

Answer (score 0):

Use `NavigationLink(_,destination:,tag:,selection:)` and bind `selection` to the relevant data from `connectionOptions`.

For a detailed explanation and example code, see https://nalexn.github.io/swiftui-deep-linking/ .